# Self referencing Entity Framework error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a field `Organization.RemappedOrganization` that is mapped to `Organization.Recno` in the database. When I try to work with the `Organization` object, I get an error:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot call Property for the property 'RemappedOrganization' on entity type 'Organization' because it is configured as a navigation property. Property can only be used to configure scalar properties.

I'm guessing I'm not setting it up correctly in Entity Framework... but not sure how.

```
public class Organization
{
    [Key]
    public int? Recno { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
    public bool PermanentlyDisplay { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RemappedOrganization")]
    public virtual Organization RemappedOrganization { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateAdded { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>().ToTable("Organization")
            .HasIndex(p => new { p.OrganizationName }).IsUnique();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the error because the attribute below is not configured correctly:

```
[ForeignKey("RemappedOrganization")]
```

You're decorating a navigation property with a `ForeignKey` attribute and specifing the same property as value of the property.

You have two options to fix the error:

- remove the attribute and let EF to generate the foreign key column for you
- add new property `RemappedOrganizationId` (which must be a scalar property) in your entity and use that property name as value for `ForeignKey`.